# Base 64 incompleto al enviar a API Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, json, base64, gson

Estoy intentando enviar una variable string que contiene un base 64 a un API, pero el base 64 siempre sale incompleto, alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Este es el codigo con que consumo el servicio web API

```
        public class PqrdA extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings){

            String CodigoEntidad = strings[0];
            int IDSecretaria = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
            int IDAsuntoInteres = Integer.parseInt(strings[2]);
            int IDCLasificacion = Integer.parseInt(strings[3]);
            String Descripcion = strings[4];
            byte[] Documentos = strings[5].getBytes();
            String NombreArchivo = strings[6];
            String ContentType = strings[7];
            String EmailCiudadano = strings[8];
            String Recepcion = strings[9];

            com.tramites.alcaldiadeelcerrito.PqrdA.Documentos documentos = new com.tramites.alcaldiadeelcerrito.PqrdA.Documentos(Documentos,
                    NombreArchivo, ContentType);

            com.tramites.alcaldiadeelcerrito.PqrdA.oPQRDAnonimaEntities oPQRDAnonimaEntities = new com.tramites.alcaldiadeelcerrito.PqrdA.oPQRDAnonimaEntities(CodigoEntidad,
                    IDSecretaria, IDAsuntoInteres, IDCLasificacion, Descripcion, documentos, EmailCiudadano, Recepcion);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(oPQRDAnonimaEntities);
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            RequestBody Body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(urlPqrdA)
                    .post(Body).build();
            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String result = response.body().string();

                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                    EstadoResult = json_data.getString("Estado");
                    Ticket = json_data.getString("Ticket");

                    if (EstadoResult.equals("true")){
                        textoMostrar = "Señor ciudadano(a). Se le informa que su trámite ha iniciado correctamente. Su número de radicado es: " + Ticket;
                        openDialogOk(textoMostrar);
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PqrdAnonima.this,
                            "En el momento no es posible realizar transaccion, comuniquese con la alcaldia municipal y reporte el error.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

La variable que tiene el base64 es la que tiene por nombre Documentos, que hace parte del objeto documentos, y luego le paso este objeto al objeto oPQRDAnonimaEntities, el cual convierto a string utilizando la libreria GSON y de esta forma enviarlo en el Body al servicio API.

Gracias.

Comment: Por qué dices que está incompleto? Viaja completo? Cómo se lo entregas al API?

Comment: Porque llega incompleto a la base de datos, al ver esto hice debug y me di cuenta que el base64 se iba incompleto y adicional a esto las variables que se vayan detras del base64 no viajan, es como si la cadena no soportara tantos caracteres.

Comment: Si estás enviando todo por GET, pasa que esas peticiones pueden ser limitadas en tamaño por el ciente, por el servidor, por equipos intermedios de seguridad, etc. Si debes enviar datos de más de 2KB, es más sano usar POST

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo por post, aun asi no me permite enviar el base64 completo

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo de un valor que envias y uno que se almacena en la base de datos? @MichaelZapata